# I am using query for retrieve data from "Group" table. Using the query "SELECT * FROM Group;". Result is, Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Group'

Tags: sql, select, datatable

select * from Group;
I want to retrieve data from "Group" table. When I run the query "select * from Group".
This statement show in the result
"Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Group'."

I try database query

```
select * from Group;
```

I expecting show all data of the "Group" table.

Comment: You've just learned it's a generally bad idea to give your table's names that are also reserved words in the language. You could escape the name but I'd strongly urge you to learn to avoid those names instead.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SQL_reserved_words, either change to a non-reserved word, or delimit as `"Group"` (might be case sensitive.)

Comment: Have you tried "select * from [Group]"?

Answer (score 1):

"Group" is a **terrible** table name! I urge you to rename it as soon as you can. In the meantime you should be able to **escape** the name by using double quotes or backticks or square brackets depending on the database you are actually using.

```
select * from "Group"; -- generic/most dbms

select * from `Group`; -- MySQL

select * from [Group]; -- MSSQL
```

Note that once you escape a table name it may also be case sensitive so it might be "group" or "Group" or "GROUP" or any combination of upper/lower case (& we cannot tell you which is correct).

Remember that a SQL query can contain the instruction to **GROUP BY** and so that is a "reserved word" e.g.

```
select code, sum(value)  as sum_value
from my_table
GROUP BY code   --<< the word GROUP is used in SQL
```

That is why naming a table "group" is such a bad idea - you will have to remember to escape that table name in every query (or, rename it to avoid that problem).